# Configure nginx to allow a bot to a single Laravel 4 route

Tags: nginx, configuration

I've got an nginx configuration for a Laravel 4 deployment. It works well, but I'm trying to make a change to prevent Twitterbot from accessing anything other than the robots.txt file (they are spamming us with traffic to update share cards, and apparently caching the robots.txt file for far too long). The issue is that since Laravel routes everything through index.php, including the robots.txt file (built in a Blade template), I'm not sure how to match the Laravel route for that file. Here's what I'm working with. Blocked just the less important bits for privacy:

```
server {
  server_name
    domain1.com
    domain2.com
    # More domains...
  ;

  root /srv/web/self-service/master/public;
  index index.html index.php;

  location / {
    # Pretty URIs, Passes Things to the ".php" location block
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  # My attempt at matching the robots.txt URL
  location ~ index\.php/robots\.txt$ {
    # Don't block Twitterbot here

    # FastCGI Params Here

    set $route "out-php-load-balancer:9000";
    fastcgi_pass $route;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    # Block Twitterbot here
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Twitterbot") {return 403;}

    # FastCGI Params Here

    set $route "our-php-load-balancer:9000";
    fastcgi_pass $route;
  }
}
```

What location do I need to put in to get it to bypass the Twitterbot check? Is there a better way to do this? I know if's are bad, but I think this is a case where I don't have a choice. I'd gladly be proven wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct URI for robots.txt is `/robots.txt`. Your approach seems perfectly valid, but you will need to hardwire the `fastcgi_param` for `SCRIPT_FILENAME` to point to `/index.php`. For example:

```
# My attempt at matching the robots.txt URL
location = /robots.txt {
    # Don't block Twitterbot here

    # FastCGI Params Here
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;

    set $route "out-php-load-balancer:9000";
    fastcgi_pass $route;
}
```

Set `SCRIPT_FILENAME` after including other fastcgi param files so that it does not get overridden.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for the location directive.

Also, `return 403` is one of the few things that you **are allowed to do** in an `if` block. See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) for details.

Comment: I can't vote yet, but this works and makes sense! Thank you!